# What infinite sums cannot be approximated in polynomial time?

Tags: reference-request, approximation-algorithms, na.numerical-analysis, computing-over-reals

The following is from the book [Geometric algorithms and combinatorial optimization](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-78240-4):

[image]

It shows an infinite sum that has an FPTAS (= an $\epsilon$-approximation can be computed using poly($1/\epsilon$) elements), and also a polynomial-time algorithm (= an $\epsilon$-approximation can be computed using poly($\log(1/\epsilon)$) elements).

This made me interested in what other infinite sums have or don't have an FPTAS or a polynomial-time algorithm (in the above sense). Specifically, what are some natural infinite sums for which no polynomial-time algorithm exists unless P=NP?

I thought the term [Diophantine approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation) is relevant, but did not find there any information about infinite series.

EDIT: to make the question more specific, I am looking for a function $f$ on natural numbers, such that

- $f(k)$ can be computed efficiently (e.g. using a constant number of arithmetic operations, or in time polynomial in $\log(k)$).
- The sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f(k)$ converges to some real number $s$.
- There is no algorithm that, for every rational number $\epsilon>0$, computes a rational number $r$ such that $|s-r|<\epsilon$, in time polynomial in $\log(1/\epsilon)$.
- Optional: there is even no such algorithm that runs in time polynomial in $1/\epsilon$.

Comment: I guess you're asking for real numbers for which it not known how to compute their first n bits in poly(n) time, but it is known how to compute them in exp(n) time?

Comment: @RobinKothari real numbers for which it is provably impossible to compute their first n bits in poly(n) time, unless P=NP.

Comment: Take the $x\in(0,1)$ where the $i$th bit (in the fractional part) is $1$ if the $i$th TM (in any standard encoding) halts on empty input, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Regarding Diophantine approximation, there's the Flint Hills sequence, $\sum{\frac1{n^3\sin^2n}}$. It's unknown whether it converges, so in particular it can't be approximated

Comment: @NealYoung I should probably ask a more specific question; please see my edit.

Comment: Let $f(n)=2^{-M}$ if $n=\langle M,1^t\rangle$ and the TM with code $M$ halts (on empty input) in exactly $t$ steps, and $f(n)=0$ otherwise. Then $f$ is poly-time computable, and the sum monotonically converges to a real between $0$ and $1$, which cannot be approximated by *any* algorithm at all (never mind its complexity). It's the Chaitin constant, basically.

Comment: What's the model of computation?  Standard TM?  Real RAM?

Comment: @NealYoung both are interesting

Comment: The constraint "time polynomial in $\log k$" seems toothless.  E.g. suppose for a given $f$ that $f(k)$ is computable only in time $2^{2^k}$.   One could replace $f$ by $g$ such that $g(i) = f(k)$ when $i = 2^{2^k}$ for some integer $k$, and $g(i) = 0$ otherwise.  Then the sum doesn't change (as $\sum_i g(i) = \sum_k f(k))$, while $g(i)$ is computable in time $O(\log i)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP asks (now in the comments) for a real number $s$ such that (among other things), one can prove that, if the first $n$ bits of $s$ can be computed in time poly$(n)$, then P$=$NP.
Perhaps the most obvious way to prove this would be to find a poly-time Turing reduction to the latter problem from some NP-hard problem.

We observe that such a reduction is unlikely to exist:

**Lemma 1.** *If there is such a reduction, then the polynomial-time hierarchy collapses to $\Delta_{2}^{P}$.*

*Proof.*

1. Fix any real number $s$.
   In what follows, by *OP's problem*, we mean the problem of
   computing the first $n$ bits of $s$ in time poly$(n)$, given $n$.
2. Define the decision problem $D_s$ as follows:

> Decision problem $D_s$:
> $~~~$ **input :** $\omega\in \{0,1\}^*$
> $~$ **output :** Is $\omega$ a prefix of the binary representation of $s$?

3. OP's problem Turing-reduces in poly-time to $D_s$.
   (Indeed, given $n$, by calling a decision procedure for $D_s$
   on one input of each length $1, 2, \ldots, n$, in a standard way,
   one can successively determine the first $n$ bits of $s$.)
4. So, if there is a poly-time Turing reduction to OP's problem from any NP-hard problem, then $D_s$ is NP-hard under Turing reductions.
5. However $D_s$ is a *sparse* language.
   (Indeed, it contains at most one word of any given size.)
6. Lemma 1 follows from Steps 4 and 5 by [Mahaney's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahaney%27s_theorem). $~~~\Box$

---

**Remarks.**
The lemma doesn't rule out proving the existence of such an $s$ by other means.  Indeed, as observed in the comments,
there are real numbers $s$ such that the problem of computing a given bit of $s$ (or approximating $s$ to an additive $\epsilon$) is undecidable.  The takeaway is perhaps that we haven't quite yet pinned down a problem definition that captures what OP is after.

OP's problem is also in P/POLY
(where we allow P/POLY to contain the *functions* that can be computed in polynomial time with polynomial advice,
as opposed to *languages*).

OP also states the following (easier) variant of his problem:

> *Given $\epsilon > 0$, compute in time polylog($1/\epsilon$) a number $r$ such that $|r-s| \le \epsilon$.*

This variant reduces to OP's problem (as defined at the top of this answer).
Specifically, the first $n$ bits of $s$ approximate $s$
to within an additive $O(2^{-n})$.
Hence, if there were a poly-time Turing reduction
from any NP-hard problem $\Pi$ to this variant,
there would also be a poly-time Turing reduction
from the NP-hard problem to OP's problem as defined here.
So, by the lemma, the poly-time hierarchy would collapse.

Comment: So computing $r$ can be undecidable, but not NP-hard? This confused me at first, until I read this: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/7676/1342

Comment: Yes.  E.g. there are many sparse undecidable languages.  Indeed, any language can be made sparse by re-encoding it in unary, which increases the input size exponentially.  This exponential increase makes no difference w.r.t. decidability, but of course makes a huge difference w.r.t. polynomial time.  In fact, it is known that there is no sparse NP-hard language unless the polynomial hierarchy collapses.  Similarly, any sparse language is in P/POLY, but P/POLY provably contains undecidable languages.